# Dynamic Breadcrumbs using sections of page for hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breadcrumbs

Working on creating a dynamic breadcrumb plugin using either jQuery or Javascript, and I do not have the knowledge to make it change dynamically while you scroll the page.

So we have a fixed header element, that will house the navigation and breadcrumbs.
While scrolling down the page, I would like the breadcrumb navigation element to change based on what section I am scrolling past.

Is this possible?

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: You are asking questions wrong. You do not edit your first question, you ask another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is possible. You can use `<name>` or `<id>` tags similar to the way you want to direct someone to a certain part of a page.

I would use those to determine whether an element is in the viewport or outside of it.

If you are okay with using a plugin you should go with the JQuery `isInViewport` plugin :

### https://plugins.jquery.com/isInViewport/

You can also take a look at the raw code and change it to your liking.

Comment: @naterchrdsn ahh nice! sweet. Glad to help.

Comment: @naterchrdsn any reason you marked it as incorrect now?